# Is there any way to convert English verbs to it's present tense on C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a Windows Phone application using C# and I want to know if there is a regular expression/library/helper or anything to get present tense verb (or base form verb) from an input verb

example:

> lived >> live
>
> built >> build
>
> working >> work

so far i found a loose solution to singularize plural words.

And I think this can be modified/added some regex rules to make it work with tenses.
But i'm not good in regex (neither English linguistics)

http://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/singularization-pluralization-in-c

My situation is:
When user trying to find some word that is not in database it will suggest something
such like typed "dragons" it will give result for "dragon"

Comment: What you want to do is called [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming). [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611455/how-to-perform-stemming-in-c) has a Porter Stemmer in C# and might be useful.

Comment: not sure if this will help, but better than nothing i guess. http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/#win

Comment: @Junuxx thanks for the keyword, it help me much understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The solution may need to be more sophisticated than you think.  Any effective approach will need to include some kind of dictionary, because there are so many irregular verbs in the English language.  The difficulty is illustrated well by considering the word "saw".  Is it a noun?  Is it a verb?  Is it the present tense of the verb "to saw"?  Is it the past tense of the verb "to see"?  This can only be inferred from context.

In short, it's not simple text processing.  There must be logic that can apply contextual processing of English phrases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I just want a loose solution to suggest something to user.

Comment: Not to mention the problem of people who don't know whether to use there, they're, or their!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using [`SharpNLP`](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/), not used it, but sure it would help you in some way also see this [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12109/Statistical-parsing-of-English-sentences).